# How to create a windows visual studios C++/CX NOT UWP?

Tags: c++, xaml

I can't find a way to create a project using C++/CX , with the XAML to define the UI, without using UWP.

Why I don't want to use UWP? because it misses lot of Windows system API, like for example FindFirstVolume.

Basically I have a set of tools I wrote in MFC and I want to port them using C++/CX XAML which looks way better.

So,is it possible, and if yes, how?

Best Regards,
Seb

Comment: There is also XAML variant for .NET implemented in WPF. *"XAML which looks way better"* - I'd say that in general XAML looks much worse, but similar visuals can be implemented using normal WinAPI. Also C++/CX is deprecated and replaced with C++/WinRT.

Comment: I'll check C++/WinRT and WPF, correct me if I am wrong but .NET is C# no?
About XAML look worse or not, is a personal taste ;)

Comment: Yes, WPF implies C# and is even more bloated than UWP XAML.

Comment: well, nope, I don't want to use C#. I guess next step I have to check if I can access DLL from C++/CX UWP project, and just do specific windows stuff in the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1279856/UWPLib-Include-XAML-Controls-in-Plain-Win32) looks like it does what you want.